# Reading pixels set using Graphics object

Tags: c#

I know several methods for reading Bitmap pixels or to get a Graphic object from an image, but what I am trying to understand is how to know what pixels have been drawn by the user by means of a Graphics object. Example: the user draw a line (but it could be any possible shape) using something like:

```
surface.DrawLine(aPen, X0, Y0, X1, Y1);
```

I need to know what pixels have been set by the user to perform some processing. This could be done quite easily for simple shapes using math (i.e. X = X0 + (X1-X0)*t) , but it seems to me possibly unefficient (specially for complex shapes). A solution I would like is to read a Bitmap looking for the pixels that have been set, but I do not know methods for getting a Bitmap image (or whatever relevant data structure) to work on from a Graphics object. Because this is an obvious need for any program allowing to the user do draw, I am for sure missing some points. Someone has a hint about this?

P.S. I am using Graphics object over a 8Bpp indexed Bitmap in a Windows Form and I need all the pixel coordinates and, possibly, the pixel values (they could be deduced from pixel coordinates, I guess)

### Proposed solution

The best solution I can figure out after the contributions in this post is something similar to this (being sourceImage the image I want to draw on and surface the picturebox control where sourceImage is rendered):

```
         private void DrawOverlay()
        {
            using (var tmpImg = new Bitmap (SourceImage.Width,SourceImage.Height, PixelFormat .Format32bppArgb))
            {
                var g = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg);
                g.DrawLine(pen1, Startx, Starty, Endx, Endy);
                tmpImg.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));
                surface.DrawImage(tmpImg, new Point (0, 0));      

// process here the tmpImg  pixels drawn by the user 

            }                 
        }
```

If someone has better answer, please, if you like, let us know; otherwise I'll close the post answering to my own question as above.

Comment: Do you need all te pixels that have been set or would the locations/pixels where the user has pressed the button suffice? Are you using Winfoms, WPF, Windows 8, ASP.NET, Silverlight, Windows Phone?

Comment: How it's different from rendering with Graphics object to bitmap, with the *same* function ? I mean create Graphics to in memory bitmap and render to it...

Comment: @Tigran: Sorry, I did not understand. The drawing is an interactive process, the user may draw complex shapes and wishes to have immediate feedback on the shapes drawn before drawing completion. Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean, if you implement DoubleBuffering *manualy*, you will have access to the in-memory (buffered) screen, so can access to pixel information from that bitmap. Cause you, I presume, activated double buffering in your app, so accessing that [BufferedGraphicsContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bufferedgraphicscontext.aspx) you will have acces to information you need, or not ?

Comment: @Tigran: I am not using double buffering at all.

Comment: @Daniel: well, may be it's time to start using it :), if there is no any contranindications..

Comment: @Tigran I know what the advantages of double buffering are; as soon as the  shapes allowed to be drawn will start to be complex I'll use it; right now double buffering for drawing a line or a polygon (no filled shapes) seems to me an overkill. Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: @Daniel: don't think so, double buffering is ok for smooth drawing, whatever is it.So, consider of using it, it's not so complicated. Can search online on how to handle it "manually" in WindowsForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the proposed solution draft in the question after the feedback received seems to be the an acceptable solution to have an easy access to the pixels drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a copy of the image before creating the Graphics context. After you have processed all paintings with the Graphics context, you can compare the image with the first one (backup) using XOR (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040174/how-images-can-be-xor-using-cs-builtin-methods)). The resulting contains only those pixels that have changed.

```
backupImage XOR drawnImage = changes
```

You can also use OpenCV wrapped by [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) and it's [Difference](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/673023f7-799a-2ef6-7933-31ef09974dde.htm) and [Substract](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/2d04f587-3272-2ad5-f8bc-54ff407d41f2.htm) classes. They do exactly what you want.